# Did mantra siddi ever happen without guru initiation?

Tags: mantras, siddhi

Either from scriptures or from history, did mantra siddi ever happen to a person by just mantra chanting, along with other conditions but without any initiation of the mantra by physical guru?

Comment: Are you looking to chant some mantras without initiation? :D

Comment: @Rickross :P ha... But not doing..